# Set button size as big as a fingertip in libgdx

Tags: android, libgdx, size, viewport, scaling

In my libgdx game I need to display a row with 8 to 14 round buttons.

I'm looking for the best way to make sure all buttons are at least the size of a fingertip (between 0.8 and 1 mm) but not much larger, because I want them to fit into the screen without scrolling if it is possible.

I've found several possible solutions, but I really don't know which is the best, or if I'm missing something better:

- Use an ExtendViewport, with virtual size 480x360 for example, and find a suitable size for the buttons. This is the easiest to implement, but the result varies depending on the screen density, size and aspect ratio.
- Use a StretchViewport, fix only the width of the buttons, and calculate their height at runtime using the device aspect ratio in order to keep them round. This also depends on the screen density and size, but not on the aspect ratio.
- Use the device density and physical size to calculate at runtime the size of the buttons. This seems a better approach to get the buttons at the right size, but is much more complex and low-level, so I find it strange that there isn't simpler ways to do this.

So, which do you think is the way to go?

Answer (score 0):

Joanq, use your (slightly modified) suggestion 2 to cover the most types of screens: Use a StretchViewport, fix only width of the buttons (**as a percentage of Gdx.graphics.getWidth()**), and calculate their height at runtime using the device aspect ratio in order to keep them round.

Comment: I don't think this works: when working with Extend or Stretch viewports you are already defining a virtual size, that is then scaled to the size of the device. So, you are already implicitly working with a percentage of the width.

Comment: This is how the viewport is defined: new ScalingViewport(Scaling.stretch, Gdx.graphics.getWidth(), Gdx.graphics.getHeight(), new OrthographicCamera()); The viewport is mapped to the screen size and then you can scale individual buttons as described. If you implicitly scale everything by deforming the viewport, then (unless you hack it together somehow), scaling individual actors on the screen is a real mission - good luck with making it work with all the types of screens out there. I can only recommend out of experience to do it this way, ultimately the decision is up to you. Happy days :-)